# How to store only value of dynmodb attribute into python variable?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am using python sdk to query for particular attribute in dynamodb

Here is my existing item looks like and attribute name is os_tools and its MAP type

```
{  "av" : { "S" : "no" },  "bp" : { "S" : "yes" },  "dc" : { "S" : "yes" },  "gl" : { "S" : "yes" },  "za" : { "S" : "no" }}
```

My boto3 program look for only item which has av and value as no

```
import boto3
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key, Attr

dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
table = dynamodb.Table(g_data')
data = table.scan(
      FilterExpression=Attr('tools_type.av').eq('no'))

print(data['Items'])
```

I am getting output as whole item. but If i want to print only where tools_type is av and i need to pull its value to a python variable ?

and also I would like query like this, when in input av it should tell me what is value for it yes or no ? like that

Answer (score 0):

```py
data = {  "av" : { "S" : "no" },  "bp" : { "S" : "yes" },  "dc" : { "S" : "yes" },  "gl" : { "S" : "yes" },  "za" : { "S" : "no" }}

print (data['av']['S'])
```